# If statement inside animate

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, if-statement

I have made a little website that should look like it is a little game. All it is, is a man you can make go right og left (it is the background that is moving) and make him jump. I have placed a box in his way so you have to jump over it before you can go on.

Now i would like him to be able to stand on the box if he didn't jump all the way across the box. - I am using an animate function to make the jump, is there a way to say the if he is between x1 and x2 on the way down, then only animate the fall to 100 px instead of all 200 px down?

[The site is right here!](http://kaspersunivers.dk/the-man/)
(Use arrow keys for walk and spacebar for jump)

This is my script to make him move and jump:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var canvas = $("#canvas");
var man = $("#man");
var distance_walked = 0;
var keyStack = {};

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    keyStack[e.keyCode] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    delete keyStack[e.keyCode];
});

updateCanvas = function() {
    //is key 39 pressed?
    if(keyStack[39]) {
        man.css('background-position', '-87px 0');

        if(canvas.css('margin-left') != '-2214px') {
            canvas.stop().animate({
                marginLeft: "-=18px"
            }, 1);
            distance_walked += 1;
            console.log('Distance moved:' + distance_walked);
        }

        if((canvas.css('margin-left') >= '-2214px') && (man.css('bottom') > '180px')) {
            canvas.stop().animate({
                marginLeft: "-=18px"
            }, 1);
            distance_walked += 1;
        }
    }
    //is key 37 pressed?
    if(keyStack[37]) {
        man.css('background-position', '-174px 0');

        if((canvas.css('margin-left') < '0px') && (canvas.css('margin-left') != '-2448px')) {
            canvas.stop().animate({
                marginLeft: "+=18px"
            }, 1)
            distance_walked -= 1;
        }

        if((canvas.css('margin-left') <= '-2448px') && (man.css('bottom') > '180px')) {
            canvas.stop().animate({
                marginLeft: "+=18px"
            }, 1)
            distance_walked -= 1;
        }
    }

    //is key 32 pressed?
    if(keyStack[32]) {
        if(!man.data('lock')) {
            man.data('lock', true);
                man.stop().animate(
                    {
                        bottom: 300 + 'px'
                    },
                    800,
                    function() {
                        man.stop().animate({
                            bottom: 120 + 'px'
                        }, 400, function() {
                            man.data('lock', false);   
                        });
                    }
                );
        }
    }

    //create a loop
    setTimeout(updateCanvas, 10);
};

updateCanvas();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was able to figure this one out!
First i made some extra variables

```
var ground_height = 120;
var jump_height = 170;
var jump = ground_height + jump_height;
var fall = jump - jump_height;
```

Then i changed the jump animation to use the calculated functions like this:

```
if((parseInt(canvas.css('margin-left'), 10) < '-2214') && (parseInt(canvas.css('margin-left'), 10) > '-2448')) {
            ground_height = 200;
            jump = ground_height + jump_height;
            fall = jump - jump_height;
}
```

The i had to make two extra if statement to make him fall down from the box on each site like this:

```
if((ground_height == 200) && (parseInt(canvas.css('margin-left'), 10) >= '-2214')) {

        ground_height = 120;
        jump = ground_height + jump_height;
        fall = jump - jump_height;

        man.animate({
            bottom: ground_height + 'px'
        },200);   
}

if((ground_height == 200) && (parseInt(canvas.css('margin-left'), 10) <= '-2448')) {

        ground_height = 120;
        jump = ground_height + jump_height;
        fall = jump - jump_height;

        man.animate({
            bottom: ground_height + 'px'
        },200);
}
```

Lastly i needed yet another if statement to make him able do walk after he was down on the ground, it looked like this:

```
if(parseInt(canvas.css('margin-left'), 10) <= '-2448') {
            canvas.stop().animate({
                marginLeft: "-=18px"
            }, 1);
}
```

Wola! That did the trio for me, i have uploaded the working result here: **[WORKING RESULT](http://kaspersunivers.dk/the-man/)** and expanded et a little bit, you are welcome to inspect the code and take anything you need :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to keep on using this approach, the landing on the box is not really viable.
Imagine, your character is up in the sky, just at the zenith of his flight: that is when your "bottom: 300 + 'px'" animation stops, then the animation at the callback is fired. You'd have to know the landing X coordinate at that instant to check for collision and thus the landing Y coord., which is - considering your current model - impossible, since I can move the charater anywhere during falling.

*In general, this approach is really off the path. I mean, this is really not the way for implementing any game. Yes, I know that you want to make a proof of concept, or just fiddle some with some jQuery code and CSS offsetting, but the farther you try to go, the more entangled you will get in these rotten grips, and burn up time thinking about features you can't, or hardly can implement.*

Comment: So there is absolute no way to achive this? It is the only thing left there is "game like" that i need. The rest of the idea is just styling and positioning the right elements the right places.

Comment: The point is that, the current method you use right now, whereas you start an animation at the top, determines the time at you will land. And if you know when you will land by the time you start falling down, you shouldn't be able to alternate between landing on it and landing near it, but as you can figure out you can alternate.

If you want to hold on to your current idea, I suggest you disable controlling your character while in air and do a simple calculation of where you'll land and THEN start an animation to land at the Y coordinate of the top of either the box or the ground.